Search Like Google Using Elasticsearch
I want to perform a search like google when the user starts typing.
My documents looks like this:
{
        "fir_number": "12345",
        "fir_id": "123",
        "accused_first_name": "spider man",
        "accused_relative_name": "super man",
        "accused_dob": "2019-05-18T10:20:03Z",
        "fir_reg_date": "2024-05-18T10:20:03Z",
        "ipc_section": "123",
        "ps_name": "police station",
        "dist_name": "district",
        "fir_status": "y",
        "fir_content": "fir content goes here..."
    }
{
        "fir_number": "12345",
        "fir_id": "123",
        "accused_first_name": "bat man",
        "accused_relative_name": "super woman",
        "accused_dob": "2019-05-18T10:20:03Z",
        "fir_reg_date": "2024-05-18T10:20:03Z",
        "ipc_section": "123",
        "ps_name": "police station",
        "dist_name": "district",
        "fir_status": "y",
        "fir_content": "fir content goes here..."
    }

I want to perform a search upon accused_first_name and accused_relative_name both these fields
Expectations:

If user starts typing they should get the suggestions.
if user types spi - they should get spider man.
If makes a typo they should get the correct suggestions.
if user types siper - they should get spider man.
If user types man, they should get suggestions like - spider man, bat man etc which all contains man here.
If user types super wo - they should get only super woman as suggestion not super man and super woman.

I have achieved the 1st and 2nd points by using completion mapping fields while creating the index
CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest.Builder().index("my_index")
    .settings(settings -> settings.numberOfShards("1").numberOfReplicas("1"))
    .mappings(
            mappings -> mappings
                    .properties("accused_first_name",
                            new Property.Builder().completion(new CompletionProperty.Builder()
                                    .analyzer("simple").preserveSeparators(true)
                                    .preservePositionIncrements(true).maxInputLength(50).build()).build())
                    .properties("accused_relative_name",
                            new Property.Builder().completion(new CompletionProperty.Builder()
                                    .analyzer("simple").preserveSeparators(true)
                                    .preservePositionIncrements(true).maxInputLength(50).build()).build()))
    .build();

CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = esJavaClient.indices().create(request);

While searching I have used the suggest query with fuzziness
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest.Builder()
    .index("my_index")
    .suggest(suggest -> suggest
            .suggesters("first_name_suggestions", suggester -> suggester
                    .text("man") 
                    .completion(completion -> completion
                            .field("accused_first_name") 
                            .fuzzy(fuzzy -> fuzzy
                                    .fuzziness("AUTO")
                                    .minLength(3)
                                    .prefixLength(1)
                                    .transpositions(true)
                            )
                    )
            )
            .suggesters("relative_name_suggestions", suggester -> suggester
                    .text("man") 
                    .completion(completion -> completion
                            .field("accused_relative_name") 
                            .fuzzy(fuzzy -> fuzzy
                                    .fuzziness("AUTO")
                                    .minLength(3)
                                    .prefixLength(1)
                                    .transpositions(true)
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
    .build();

But when I type only man I am not getting any result, but the expectations is to get the results which contains man in first_name and relative_name. I went through multiple articles and got to know that The completion suggester cannot perform full-text queries, which means that it cannot return suggestions based on words in the middle of a multi-word field ref link.

I came across edge n-gram token but in this way I am bit concerned about the performance as it will create a lot tokens for each of the doc which will gradually increase the size.
I have more than 10 million records and it will increase day by day, so which is the best way to achieve the search in this scenario is it okay to go with edge n-gram and match query with fuziness or is there any other efficient way?

discuss.elastic
Thanks
